# What name is the '--name' CLI option referring to?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I'm updating an SSL certificate (using SSL add on, not ACM). CLI is telling me that I need to specify `--name`, but I have no idea what name it is referring to.

`$ heroku certs:update --app=myapp --type=endpoint myapp.crt myapp.key 
 ▸    Must pass --name when more than one endpoint`

I tried specifying the app name and the DNS name, and I haven't found a description of that option in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

The name used with the `--name` option is the endpoint name as reported by the following:

`$ heroku certs --app myapp
Name          Endpoint                    Common Name(s) Expires
Trusted Type
───────────── ─────────────────────────── ────────────── ────────────────────
───────  ────────
sushibar-1234 sushibar-1234.herokussl.com myapp.foo.com  2021-04-01 19:45 UTC
True     Endpoint`

There might be more than one name if you have more than one endpoint.